# Templates are mind bending... Need assistance (besides methadone)

Tags: c++, templates

Having an issue (yeah, ok I got issues)... with template methods. In the example below I have a template method DoIt, the actual piece of code works fine. The template method knows the actual size of the buffer being passed (N). But I also want the option of being able to call DoIt passing only a buffer address and a length). That is my method DoItThisWay.

How do I have DoItThisWay call DoIt in such a way as to limit the size of the buffer recognized by DoIt as only have length siz, as passed to DoItThisWay?

```
template<typename T, size_t N> size_t DoIt(T(&buf)[N], size_t siz) 
{
    // Work done here...
    return 0;
}

size_t DoItThisWay(uint8_t buf[], size_t siz)
{
    return DoIt.........
}
```

Comment: Why not do it the other way around and have a `DoIt` call `DoItThisWay(buf, siz)`?

Comment: I thought about that, and was actually about to do just that, but then I figured I snip the tiger's tail and ask the forum to see if there was an answer? Seriously though, Not modifying the original code to insert the new calling overload would be good to know. Thanks by the way!

Comment: Why do you have both `N` and `siz`? If they have distinct meanings then how does the second function that only has one of the two relate to it

Answer (score 2):

In a function argument, `uint8_t buf[]` is just syntax sugar for `uint8_t *buf`.

You cannot pass a raw pointer where a reference to a fixed array is expected. Even if you could, you cannot pass a runtime value like `siz` to a template parameter, only constants that are known  at compile-time. So, `DoItThisWay` simply cannot call `DoIt`.

However, a fixed array decays into a pointer to its first element, so `DoIt` can call `DoItThisWay`, but only when `T` is `uint8_t`, thus making `T` redundant (unless you have multiple overloads of `DoItThisWay` for different data types, or give `DoItThisWay` it's own `T` template parameter).

Either way, the `siz` argument of `DoIt` is redundant and should be removed since `DoIt` can use `N` instead.

Try this:

```
size_t DoItThisWay(uint8_t *buf, size_t siz)
{
    // Work done here...
    return 0;
}

template<size_t N>
size_t DoIt(uint8_t(&buf)[N])
{
    return DoItThisWay(buf, N);
}
```

Or

```
size_t DoItThisWay(uint8_t *buf, size_t siz)
{
    // Work done here...
    return 0;
}

// other overloads of DoItThisWay...

template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t DoIt(T(&buf)[N])
{
    return DoItThisWay(buf, N);
}
```

Or

```
template<typename T>
size_t DoItThisWay(T *buf, size_t siz)
{
    // Work done here...
    return 0;
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t DoIt(T(&buf)[N])
{
    return DoItThisWay(buf, N);
}
```

Comment: Easy there Remy... you must moonlight as a rapid fire pistol champion. I can only digest one solution at a time. lol Thanks!!!

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - T(&buf)[N] - buf is a reference to an array size of N of type T.  So buf is pointer to every Nth array element. e.g. Lets say int n[10][10].  &n[0] has address of first 10 rows. &n[1] has address of second 10th row so and so forth.  So what you are saying is that, N is not defined at the compilation time, this is not possible. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: I appreciate the fact that there are some really smart people out there. But I am also sure that if they are really smart that they have an idea of what I was looking for, right or wrong.  I guess at some point we could argue about whether or not we should call it bur or N or siz. But more importantly it's  important to help those of us that don't know, rather than ask questions with the hopes that everyone else will  think you're really smart. We all now people on this site are smart.

Comment: @Nguaial no. By virtue of being a template parameter, `N` **must** be known at compile time, and it can be deduced by the compiler based on the type of fixed array passed to `buf`. Passing an `int[X]` makes `T=int` and `N=X`. Passing an `int[X][Y]` makes `T=int[Y]` and `N=X`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to call `DoIt` from `DoItThisWay` since it knows only the type but not the size at compile time. You need both to call `DoIt`.

```
size_t DoItThisWay(uint8_t buf[], size_t siz)
{
    // What value of N can you use here?
    return DoIt.........
}
```

BTW, passing `siz` to `DoIt` is superfluous. You already know the size. It is `N`.

Comment: You're BTW is one of the hazards of trying to make an example out of real world code. But I appreciate the comment. I see your point, as disappointing as it is. I was hoping to insert a simple overload without having to modify the original. Time for a Twizzler to soothe away the pout.